# IIS 7 static file compression problem

Tags: iis-7, compression

We have 3 web servers running IIS7. I've enabled compression for static and dynamic content. We have been testing the servers under heavy load and after half an hour the styles on the site started breaking.

I started investigating and found out that IIS was serving css and js files with **Content-Encoding: gzip** but the actual file content is not compressed. This cause the browsers to give error when trying to process the content. The issue disappears if I restart IIS.

Have anyone experienced a similar issues? What is the best way to diagnose the issue?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem with IIS 7.5, any solutions?

Comment: The problem was caused by the CMS (sitecore) we were using. We upgraded to a later version and it has worked ever since. It's probably a 3rd party httpmodule causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the CMS (sitecore) we were using. We upgraded to a later version and it has worked ever since. It's probably a 3rd party httpmodule causing the issue.

Comment: What version of Sitecore were you using and what version did you upgrade to? We're having the same problem.

Comment: We didn't want to upgrade Sitecore so we just excluded our CSS, image and javascript directories from the Sitecore pipeline.

Comment: We went to the latest version of 6.2.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969062 ?

KR, Thomas

Comment: I had a look there but I think the problem I'm having is caused by a third party httpmodule I'm using.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Our site was failing to pull JS and CSS in when the page was refreshed after loading.

I switched static file compression off in IIS 7.5, and the site was fine again. This led me to do some investigation into why this might be happening.

For us, the problem occurred because the site had some legacy code that programmatically implemented GZIP encoding, and IIS 7.5 was conflicting with it. We removed the legacy code, and switched static file compression back on.